# Higher Ext groups of a $0$ Ext group

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Suppose me have two $A$ modules, $M$, and $N$. It Ext$_A^1(M,N)=0$, is it necessarily the case that higher order ext groups are $0$ as well? In every example I've worked with so far, this has been the case. However, it's not immediately obvious to me that it should always be the case.

If $M$ is projective, then Ext$_A^1(M,N)=0$, but if we find the higher order Ext groups, I see no reason that the left entry in $\text{Ext}_A^1(-,\ N)$ remains projective, in which case, there's no reason that Ext remains $0$. As I said before, every example I've computed stays zero once one of the Ext groups are $0$, but I'm not sure that this need always be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $A=\mathbb{Z}_p[[t]]$ and $N=A$, $M=\mathbb{F}_p$. Then $Ext^r_A(M,N)$ is nonzero exactly when $r=2$.

Answer (score 1):

One thing we can say in general is the following Exercise 2.5.2 in Weibel: if $Ext^1(M,N)$ vanishes for all N, then $Ext^i(M,N)$ vanishes for all $i\neq 0$ and all $N$. This is equivalent to $M$ being projective